# Translate WPBakery in Wordpress Admin

Tags: wordpress, admin, translate, wpbakery

Please forgive me, but i am kinda new to coding. I only need one word translated and was hoping to not need a translating plugin installed on my site. I have translated the word "Shopping Cart" on the cart-page using the following css-code:

```
.woocommerce-cart .woocommerce > form > h1 {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;

}
.woocommerce-cart .woocommerce > form > h1:after {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: 'Handlekurv' !important;
}
```

But when i try to translate the WPBakery Page Builder in the admin-menu, nothing happens. I have tried the following code, but i think there is something wrong with the class:

```
.wp-has-submenu .wp-has-current-submenu .wp-menu-open .menu-top #toplevel_page_vc-general {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;

}

.wp-has-submenu .wp-has-current-submenu .wp-menu-open .menu-top #toplevel_page_vc-general:after {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: 'Page Builder' !important;
}
```

```
<li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_vc-general" id="toplevel_page_vc-general"><a href="admin.php?page=vc-general" class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_vc-general" aria-haspopup="true"><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><div class="wp-menu-image dashicons-before" aria-hidden="true"><img src="https://hygg.no/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/vc/logo/wpb-logo-white_32.svg" alt=""></div><div class="wp-menu-name">WPBakery Page Builder</div></a>
    <ul class="wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap"><li class="wp-submenu-head" aria-hidden="true">WPBakery Page Builder</li><li class="wp-first-item"><a href="admin.php?page=vc-general" class="wp-first-item">General Settings</a></li><li><a href="admin.php?page=vc-roles">Role Manager</a></li><li><a href="admin.php?page=vc-updater">Product License</a></li><li><a href="admin.php?page=vc-welcome">About</a></li></ul></li>
<a href="admin.php?page=vc-general" class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_vc-general" aria-haspopup="true"><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><div class="wp-menu-image dashicons-before" aria-hidden="true"><img src="https://hygg.no/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/vc/logo/wpb-logo-white_32.svg" alt=""></div><div class="wp-menu-name">WPBakery Page Builder</div></a>
<div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div>
<div class="wp-menu-image dashicons-before" aria-hidden="true"><img src="https://hygg.no/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/vc/logo/wpb-logo-white_32.svg" alt=""></div>
<div class="wp-menu-name">WPBakery Page Builder</div>
<a href="admin.php?page=vc-general" class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_vc-general" aria-haspopup="true"><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><div class="wp-menu-image dashicons-before" aria-hidden="true"><img src="https://hygg.no/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/vc/logo/wpb-logo-white_32.svg" alt=""></div><div class="wp-menu-name">WPBakery Page Builder</div></a>
<ul class="wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap"><li class="wp-submenu-head" aria-hidden="true">WPBakery Page Builder</li><li class="wp-first-item"><a href="admin.php?page=vc-general" class="wp-first-item">General Settings</a></li><li><a href="admin.php?page=vc-roles">Role Manager</a></li><li><a href="admin.php?page=vc-updater">Product License</a></li><li><a href="admin.php?page=vc-welcome">About</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: Do you have the HTML code for this page?

Comment: I have edited in the HTML code now :)

Answer (score 0):

Given your html code, adding this to your CSS will replace all instances of WPBakery Page Builder with Page Builder.

```
.wp-menu-name, .wp-submenu-head{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.wp-menu-name:after, .wp-submenu-head:after {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: 'Page Builder' !important;
    }
```

Though definitely test this as looking at this without further context of html on the whole page/site it might effect other items as well.